# java mvn: package javax.activation does not exist and mvn install not solving it

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build the following package with mvn:
https://github.com/mbechler/marshalsec

I get this error:
`[...]JDKUtil.java:[52,24] package javax.activation does not exist`

I tried downloading javax.activation from:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1

and installing like this:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=activation-1.1.1.jar -DgroupId=javax.activation -DartifactId=activation -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar`

It seems to installed successfully:

```
[INFO] Installing [...]\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall13250992682429266805.pom to [...]\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.050 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-22T17:31:35+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I am still getting the same error.
Am I fetching the javax.activation from the wrong place?
Am I not installing it correctly?

Thanks ahead

**EDIT: adding info**, output of mvn help:effective-pom
https://pastebin.com/0LP7BGZK

Comment: What version of Java are you running locally?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: strange... module javax.activation has been removed only from JAVA 11

Comment: I also don't see it listed as a dependency (explicitly) in that project's POM.  Edit your question with the result of `mvn help:effective-pom` so we can see where this dependency exists.

Comment: Just run this command and add the output to my question?

Comment: That is what he means.

Comment: Added as link to pastebin due to length of error

Answer (score 2):

edit the pom.xml file within the main marshalsec directory and add a new dependency under the 'Util' section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and always ensure proper indentation